# JS: Compare strings of an array with object fields

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an object, which represents the role of an user:

```
const user = {
  isEditor: false,
  isAdmin: true,
  isTranslator: false
}
```

I need to pass some elements to a function an check if any of this role has a true value in the user object.

```
result = hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'admin']) // true
result = hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'translator']) // false
```

I've some problems with that, as the roles are named a bit differently.
I thought also about using `_.some()` as I need to check for only one true value.

```
function hasPermission (user, roles) {
  roles.forEach(role => {
    user[role] // is not working as user keys named differently
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you forced to give different names to your keys? It would be really simpler and not that uglier.

Comment: @sjahan If it is really much more easy, I could change the role array string names... Not the object keys.

Comment: `return user["is" + "admin".slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + "admin".slice(1)];`

Comment: @user3142695 if the syntax always stay the same, it's not a very big problem, check my solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution the closest to your situation, without changing the shape of your objects and functions.

You can actually use `some` like this, it is quite simple:

```js
const user = {
  isEditor: false,
  isAdmin: true,
  isTranslator: false
};

function hasPermission (user, roles) {
  return roles.some(role => user["is" + role[0].toUpperCase() + role.substring(1)]);
}

console.log(hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'admin']));
console.log(hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'translator']));
```

Hoping this will help you!

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is not the proper way to think about it.

A users role are not individual properties, rather a collection of roles.
So your user object should be model like

```
const MyUser = {
  roles: ["Admin","Editor"]
}
```

So then you can check if a user has a given role by working with a function like so :

```
function UserHasAnyRole(user,roleKeys)
{
    if(user && user.roles && roleKeys && roleKeys.length)
    {
        return user.roles.filter(function(r){
            return roleKeys.filter(function(k){ return k == r;}).length>0; 
        }).length > 0;

    }       
    return false;    
}

var neededRoles = ["Admin","Translator"];

if(UserHasAnyRole(MyUser,neededRoles))
{
// do stuff
}
```

This way of thinking about it scales much better, as individual properties is not a sustainable way in the long term

EDIT: to account for arrray of input roles. This is not tested tho, so there might be some syntax errors in there, but you get the idea...

Comment: That's a very good point. Thanks for that. But if I change the structure like you recommend, I still have the input of multpile roleKeys, which I want to check if any is matching for the user.

Comment: Please review the answer, i forgot to account for the multiple inputs

Comment: @MKougiouris - here are some code improvements: 1) Export the string literals as constants in a separate "roles.sj" module e.g. `export const ADMIN = "Admin";`; 2) swap `if` logic for readability i.e. `if(!user || !user.roles || !roleKeys || !roleKeys.length) { return false; } ...`; 3) Simplify Array functions & put in lambda shorthand (the author tagged this with `ES6`): `return user.roles.find(role => roleKeys.find(roleKey => role === roleKey));`

Comment: Indeed, good points all of them, maybe with the exception of the 'export' just because i am not familiar enough with it yet and i would probably not use it in a correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same property names, `Object.entries()` to get an array of property, values pairs of the object and `Array.prototype.some()` and `Array.prototype.includes()` to check if the values match

```js
const user = {
  isEditor: false,
  isAdmin: true,
  isTranslator: false
}

const hasPermission = (o, keys) =>
  Object.entries(o).some(([key, prop]) => prop && keys.includes(key));

let result = hasPermission(user, ["isEditor", "isAdmin"]);

console.log(result);

result = hasPermission(user, ["isEditor", "isTranslator"]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution.

```js
const user = {
  isEditor: false,
  isAdmin: true,
  isTranslator: false
};

function hasPermission (user, roles) {
  const userRoles = Object
                      .entries(user)
                      .filter(([_, val]) => val)
                      .map(([key, _]) => key.replace('is', '').toLowerCase());
                      
  return roles.some(x => userRoles.includes(x));
  
}

console.log(hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'admin']));
console.log(hasPermission(user, ['editor', 'translator']));
```